# gethostbyaddr returns 0

Tags: c++

I have a a variable that contains an IP address.  I am trying to do an nslookup on that by instead of the DNS name being returned I get 0.  I am in a Linux environment.  Destination IP comes from a vector (string dest_ip = vector[2]).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void split(const std::string& str, std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    ss >> std::noskipws;
    std::string field;
    char ws_delim;
    while(1) {
        if( ss >> field )
            v.push_back(field);
        else if (ss.eof())
            break;
        else
            v.push_back(std::string());
        ss.clear();
        ss >> ws_delim;
    }
}

int main()
{

  string input_line;

  while(cin){

  getline(cin, input_line);

   for(int i=0; input_line[i]; i++)
                      if(input_line[i] == ':') input_line[i] = ' ';
                     for(int i=0; input_line[i]; i++)
                      if(input_line[i] == '/') input_line[i] = ' ';

  std::vector<std::string> v;
  split(input_line, v);

  string dest_ip = v[4];

  struct hostent *he;
  int i,len,type;
  len = dest_ip.length();
  type=AF_INET;

  he = gethostbyaddr(dest_ip.c_str(),len,type);

  cout<<"Hostname: "<<he<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Again, instead of receiving the host name I get 0.

Comment: Why not show your real code?  Your example won't even compile.

Comment: Where is `desp_ip` getting set?

Comment: too many double quotes on your cout line

Comment: Added real code and I fat fingered the extra double quote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass a *c-style-string*  (ie. null-terminated) directly to `gethostbyaddr`.

You'll need to create a `struct in_addr` and pass a pointer to the created struct as first parameter to `gethostbyaddr`. To generate a `struct in_addr` from a `char const*` use [`inet_aton`](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?3+inet_aton).

The below example is taken from *man gethostbyaddr*:

---

**EXAMPLES**

- Print out the hostname associated with a specific IP address:

  ```
  const char *ipstr = "127.0.0.1";
  struct in_addr ip;
  struct hostent *hp;

  if (!inet_aton(ipstr, &ip))
          errx(1, "can't parse IP address %s", ipstr);

  if ((hp = gethostbyaddr((const void *)&ip, sizeof ip, AF_INET)) == NULL)
          errx(1, "no name associated with %s", ipstr);

   printf("name associated with %s is %s\n", ipstr, hp->h_name);
  ```

---

**How do I do further checks to pin-point what went wrong?**

If your use of `gethostbyaddr` returns `NULL` you should check what went wrong by looking at the variable `h_errno`.

`h_errno` can have one of the below defined values:

1. `HOST_NOT_FOUND`
2. `TRY_AGAIN`
3. `NO_RECOVERY`
4. `NO_DATA`

Please consult your manual for more details regarding the issue.

---

<strike><sup>**Your snippet is completely wrong..**</sup></strike>

<sup>The snippet provided by you doesn't even compile, but you are in a way showing what you are trying to accomplish but I cannot know this for certain.</sup>
<sup>This post contains details that should be considered to be "*educated guesses*".</sup>

<sup>OP changed his post..</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[`gethostbyaddr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a null pointer whenever some error occurs. The error could be a bad IP address, an unknown host, a misconfigured DNS setup, etc. You need to check the actual error code. On Winsock, that will mean calling [`WSAGetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), while on POSIX (I think) you need to check the value of [`h_errno`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_gethostbyaddr.htm?rd=1). (I could be wrong on POSIX, I don't have experience there)

Comment: +1 and following the MSDN `gethostbyaddr()` is deprecated in favour of `getnameinfo()`.

Comment: This post is kind of misleading, it's "obvious" that OP is trying to pass an invalid value as the first argument of `gethostbyaddr`.

Comment: @refp: The code that was posted when I originally posted this answer did not compile, and the OP was not posting details. The best I was able to do was post docs. The question has since been updated making this not the best answer (though still, I contend, not a bad answer). I've +1'd your answer, though; it is better given the OP's updated code.

Comment: @BillyONeal the content of my answer was written before his edit, though. (as can be seen in the post)

Answer (score 1):

```
    class CIPManager
{
public:
    CIPManager()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult;
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
            //return 1;
        }
    }

    bool getPCName(unsigned long ip,char* hostname)//string& strIP)
    {
        DWORD dwRetval;
        //char hostname[NI_MAXHOST];
        char servInfo[NI_MAXSERV];
        u_short port = 27015;
        //hostname=NULL;

        // Validate the parameters
        /*if (argc != 2) {
            printf("usage: %s IPv4 address\n", argv[0]);
            printf("  to return hostname\n");
            printf("       %s 127.0.0.1\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }*/
        // Initialize Winsock
        /*
        */
        //-----------------------------------------
        // Set up sockaddr_in structure which is passed
        // to the getnameinfo function
        saGNI.sin_family = AF_INET;
        saGNI.sin_addr.s_addr =ip;// inet_addr(strIP);
        saGNI.sin_port = htons(port);

        //-----------------------------------------
        // Call getnameinfo
        dwRetval = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &saGNI,
            sizeof (struct sockaddr),
            hostname,
            NI_MAXHOST, servInfo, 
            NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV);

        if (dwRetval != 0) {
            printf("getnameinfo failed with error # %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            //return 1;
            return NULL;
        } else {
        //  printf("getnameinfo returned hostname = %s\n", hostname);
            //return hostname;
            return 1;
        }
    }

protected:
private:
    struct sockaddr_in saGNI;

};
```

Use **getnameinfo** is a better solution!